# Check if value exists inside nested array in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im trying to check if a value I sent as a request already exists in an array inside of a specific User. The format of the data is as so

```json
{
    "_id": "63233972df0f14076e027106",
    "firstName": "mako",
    "lastName": "mako",
    "userName": "mako",
    "email": "mako@gmail.com",
    "friends": [
        "Josh"
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Im sending the following request

```json
{
    "userName": "mako",
    "friend": "Josh"
}
```

And I want to check if "friend" in request already exists in the data set and return a true or false.

I've tried using $exists and $in but I cant get to get the syntax right

```js
const checkFriend = async(req, res, next)=>{
  try {
    const {userName, friend} = req.body
    const check = await User.findOne({userName: userName, $in: {friends: friend}})
    res.send(check)
  } catch (error) {
    
  }
}
```

My NodeJS code for my attempt, the only one that returned anything

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct but little syntax issue. Try this

```
const check = await User.find({userName: userName, friends: { $in: [friend] }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `$in`. Mongo will check whole array if you just do this:

```js
const isFound = await User.findOne({ userName: userName, friends: friend }).lean();

if (isFound) {
  // Do something
} else {
  // Do something else
}
```

Comment: Its just returning the normal data set with the whole user while I want it to return a true/false statement, would you recommend I I use the data set to check afterwards instead ?

Comment: Hi. Yes, you can check if MongoDB found the match or not. Based on that, you can do your business logic. Also, I recommend you to add `lean()` on the query, since that will increase the performance. I updated my answer.

Comment: If you're not using any fields from the document and just want to know if the user with that criteria exists or not, use `User.exists({ userName, friends: friend });` instead. Under the hood, `.exists` makes MongoDB only return the `_id` of the document if it exists, which makes the load on the network and nodejs side much lighter.

see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-exists